# Ext Js: How to load a store from List<String>

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

This is my JSON data returned from the server. I am not seeing my combo getting loaded. What is wrong here?

```
{"suffixList":["-1","-2","-3"]}
```

***Model:***

```
Ext.define('ExtMVC.model.Suffix', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'suffix'}
    ]
});
```

***Store:***

```
 Ext.define('ExtMVC.store.Suffixes', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
        model: 'ExtMVC.model.Suffix',
        autoLoad : false,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'http://'+window.location.host+'/populateCombo',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'suffixList'
            }
        }
    });
```

***View:***

```
{
                xtype:'combo',
                id: 'suffix',
                name: 'suffix',
                store   : 'Suffixes',
                displayField: 'suffix',
                valueField: 'suffix'
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [ArrayStore](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.data.ArrayStore)

```
new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
    fields: ['suffix'],
    data: {suffixList: ['-1', '-2', '-3']},
    proxy: {
        type:'memory', //'ajax'
        reader: {
            type: 'array',
            root: 'suffixList'
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The data is not formatted correctly.  Each record should be an object, with properties for the store's fields.  In your case, the data should look like this:

```
{"suffixList":[{"suffix": "-1"},{"suffix": "-2"},{"suffix": "-3"}]}
```

Comment: I can't get the data in this format. Is there a way to change the ExtJs model and store definition in a way this data is read successfully?

Comment: If there is, I am not aware of it.  It may not be ideal, but without control over your server response format, you could always make the ajax call using `Ext.Ajax.request()`, and use `store.loadData(myArray.map(function(x) { return { suffix: x } }));` on the array result.